# Loop within thread-sequential or concurrent?

Tags: python, linux, centos, python-multithreading

If I use for and while loops within a thread and start that thread multiple times, then would my code run sequentially or concurrently? 
I am using CentOS-Linux and I want to send http request from virtual IP addresses like eth0:0,eth0:1,eth0:2,etc simultaneously with eth0. I am actually trying to make one traffic generator tool using python. I used cURL command to send request from a list of my virtually generated ips (written in iplist in sourceip.sh file) to multiple files on my server (enlisted in urllist.txt file). I am saving the status of my request in outputfile.txt file. 
Now what I want to know is weather i have been able to achieve my goal or not? Is my code running sequentially or concurrently? here is my code...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Its always sequentially.Python read codes starting by top** When a loop is done, it will start another one after that loop.

```
while ...:
for .....:
```

if its like this, after "while" loop is done its going go read "for" loop.

```
while ...:
    for.....:
```

if its like this, it will run "for" loop till "while" loop is done

for example:

```
a=0
while a<5:
    a+=1
    print "vys"
for x in range(1,10)
    print x
```

**This one will print vys 5 times, after then it will print x from 1 to 10 like 1 2 3 4..**

```
a=0
while a<5:
    a+=1
    print "vys"
    for x in range(1,10)
        print x
```

**This one will print vys 5times, after then it will print x 5 times too. Because its in while loop,read starting by top.So last one will print x 5times from 1 to 10 like 1 2 3 4.. 1 2 3 4.. 1 2 3 4.. But its sequentially as I said, so you will see this codes like this:** *vys,1 2 3 4..(5times),vys(4times more)*

Comment: but I am starting that thread multiple times without waiting for the previous one get joined.. so would'nt that be concurrent?

Comment: no my friend, its never concurrent. Python always read them starting by top as I said

Comment: but threads run concurrently right? so if i use loops within a thread wouldn't that be concurrent?

Comment: @qqV I don't see your example starting any new thread as OP is asking. Can you example more?

Comment: no its ALWAYS sequentially my friend. first of all you have to use them at the same line like example 1 that I wrote on top or like example 2. You see, example 2 is different. "for" loop is in "while" loop thats why that codes will print x 5times too. because till "while" loop is done(it means a=5) it will do whatever include "while" loop

Comment: @SSC the first example has two new threads "while" and "for". second one has only one "while" and include "for" in that

Comment: @qqV From [Python online document](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/_thread.html?highlight=thread#module-_thread), python start thread with `_thread.start_new_thread()`.  However, I don't see you using any of the thread related function in your example.  You only use loops in your examples.

Comment: @SSC my point is, its never concurrently. function or loop doesnt matter its always reading them in order, not at the same time..

Comment: Hey friends I have edited my question and attached my code to it.. can now anyone tell me weather my code runs concurrently or sequentially?